# TFS command error after upgrade from 2013 to 2015

Tags: tfs-2015

we recently upgraded team foundation server 2013 update 5 to 2015 update 2 and now when we visit the activity log, we see this weird log saying          `module_endrequest_noassoicatedmethod`
[image]

is this common or something we need to worry about? i can't find anything about this error on web.

Comment: Did you get any error or exception in  event log on the server? Seems just a end request info according to the  name.

Comment: no, i don't get any exception or error. it's just logging in the tfs log every few seconds.